# I want to create a VM in Azure, that image I created with Packer. How can I now use Azure AD login. This field is not selectable?

Tags: linux, azure, azure-active-directory, virtual-machine, packer

I created a Linux image with Packer and saved it to Azure.

Now I want to create a VM with my image.

The field in Administration Log in with Azure AD is hidden and I cannot select it.

Does anyone have a tip on how I can make this happen?

No solutions available

Answer (score 0):

As per [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/build-image-with-packer), created Linux image with packer like below:

[image]

```
==> azure-arm: Running builder ...
==> azure-arm: Getting tokens using client secret
==> azure-arm: Getting tokens using client secret
    azure-arm: Creating Azure Resource Manager (ARM) client ...
==> azure-arm: Getting source image id for the deployment ...
==> azure-arm:  -> SourceImageName: '/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-2b83a074c23f/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/East US/publishers/canonical/ArtifactTypes/vmimage/offers/0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy/skus/20_04-lts/versions/latest'
==> azure-arm: Creating resource group ...
==> azure-arm:  -> ResourceGroupName : 'pkr-Resource-Group-xunxv1zls6'
==> azure-arm:  -> Location          : 'East US'
==> azure-arm:  -> Tags              :
==> azure-arm:  ->> dept : Engineering
==> azure-arm:  ->> task : Image deployment
==> azure-arm: Validating deployment template ...
==> azure-arm:  -> ResourceGroupName : 'pkr-Resource-Group-xunxv1zls6'
==> azure-arm:  -> DeploymentName    : 'pkrdpxunxv1zls6'
==> azure-arm: Deploying deployment template ...
==> azure-arm:  -> ResourceGroupName : 'pkr-Resource-Group-xunxv1zls6'
==> azure-arm:  -> DeploymentName    : 'pkrdpxunxv1zls6'
```

***Output***:

[image]

Now when I tried to create virtual machine with that image by default Azure does not support log in with azure AD like below:

[image]

- You can authenticate using SSH keys rather than Azure AD for virtual machines running Linux. Select "SSH public key" from the list of options under "Authentication type" and enter your public SSH key. The virtual machine can now be accessed through SSH.
- If you specifically require Azure AD authentication for your Linux-based virtual machine, After the VM has been created, you can manually configure Azure AD authentication by connecting to it using SSH.

***Reference***:

[Log in to a Linux virtual machine in Azure by using Azure AD and OpenSSH - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-linux)